# Очистить данные в двух таблицах на двух разных страницах, при помощи AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, как очистить таблицы при помощи AJAX,

```
function funcSuccess(data){
            $("#tableId > tbody").empty();
            $('tbody').append(data);
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#reload").click(function(){                  
                $(this).button('loading');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "templates/brain.php",
                        success: funcSuccess,
                        complete: function () {
                            btn.html('Обновить данные');
                            btn.removeClass('loading');
                        }
                    });
            }); 
        });
```

Первая таблица так очищается, как показано в funcSuccess, а вот на другой странице, таблицу "id=table2Id" не знаю как к ней обратится.

Comment: На другой странице нужен свой скрип - он и поменяет таблицу

Answer (score 0):

$("#**table2Id** > tbody").empty();

Вот так.

```js
function funcSuccess(data, id) {
  $("#" + id + " > tbody").empty();
  $('tbody').append(data);
}
```

По хорошему написать универсальную функцию.

Comment: $("#" + id + " > tbody").empty(); чем это отличается от $("#table2Id > tbody").empty() тогда?

Comment: Просто универсальная. Вы же не будите же писать для каждей таблицы отдельную фунцию.

Comment: Можно ли вообще обратиться на прямую из одной страницы где находится таблица к другой таблице?

Comment: Можн. Все можно.

Comment: по конкретней. как очистить таблицу которая находится на второй странице из первой страницы? простое обращение не работает. и на сервере нету информации о второй страницы т.к она подгружается другим путём, через пути. get запросом

Comment: Вы напишите код. А я напишу как конкретно это сделать. Иначе никак. Надеюсь я вас правильно понимаю что обе таблицы находятся в одном html странице. Не важно подругужается или нет.

Comment: да на разных страницах они находятся, вот в чём суть

Comment: Тогда это реализуется уже спомощю php и ajax.
1)Предположем на первая страница - это страница клиента. И он выбирает товар. Не перегружая страницу, через ajax. Кол-во товара меняется на серевере.
2)Предположем вторая страница открыта для админа который следит за кол-вом товара. Он тоже не перегружает страницу. На странице админа каждые 10 секунд посылается запрос на сервер. Если кол-во изминилось. То таблица с кол-вом товаров обновляется на актуальную.

Comment: ну это понятно, думал что в js можно как то напрямую обратиться.

Comment: Другими словами. Хронить что происходит на обоих страницах должен сервер. А Ajax через каждый N секунд проверять, что изминилось.